# How to create a Django form with a RadioSelect field, and some buttons disabled?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a Django form with a set of Radio buttons (as a single RadioSelect field), and I'd like to have *some* of the buttons grayed out. However, given that the RadioSelect field is a *single* field on the form, I haven't found a way to do that.

```
class OrderStatusForm(forms.Form):
    os = Order_Status.objects.values_list('id', 'status')
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=os, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

def makeForm():
    newForm = OrderStatusForm()
    # next line disables all radio buttons.
    newForm.fields['status'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

Is there some way to *selectively* disable the individual radio buttons? Or do I just have to not put the disabled options in the list in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Further research turned up the fact that the RadioSelect `renderer` can be *replaced*, and passed in as a parameter to the initial widget creation function. So I created my own renderer, and attached a list of Booleans, indicating which Radio buttons should be disabled.

The renderer adds a *disabled* attribute to each Radio button widget as needed, then the *force_unicode* turns the widget's attributes into HTML that include a `disabled="True"` value.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode

class RandomRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
    """ Modifies some of the Radio buttons to be disabled in HTML,
    based on an externally-appended Actives list. """
    def render(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "actives"): # oops, forgot to add an Actives list
            return self.original_render()
        return self.my_render()

    def original_render(self):
        return mark_safe(u'<ul>\n%s\n</ul>' % u'\n'.join([u'<li>%s</li>'
            % force_unicode(w) for w in self]))

    def my_render(self):
        midList = []
        for x, wid in enumerate(self):
            if self.actives[x] == False:
                wid.attrs['disabled'] = True
            midList.append(u'<li>%s</li>' % force_unicode(wid))
        finalList = mark_safe(u'<ul>\n%s\n</ul>' % u'\n'.join([u'<li>%s</li>'
            % w for w in midList]))
        return finalList

class OrderStatusForm(forms.Form):
    os = Order_Status.objects.values_list('id', 'status', 'reason')
    activeList = [True, False, True, False, True, False,]
    newStatus = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(
        renderer=RandomRenderer), choices=os)
    newStatus.widget.renderer.actives = activeList
```

It's a little kludgy - I'm just sticking the *actives* list directly onto the renderer, which works (love Python's duck-typing), but would be cleaner if I passed the list in some constructors. Unfortunately I had problems with that, so took the easy way out. :)

Comment: A simpler way would be to override the `create_option` method of `forms.RadioSelect` and adding `attrs['disabled'] = True` where needed, before calling the super-method.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=os, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'disabled':'disabled'}))
```

or

```
class OrderStatusForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderStatusForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['status'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'

    os = Order_Status.objects.values_list('id', 'status')
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=os, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Comment: That's no different from what I posted - `status` is considered a *single field* (with multiple radio buttons), and the whole thing is disabled. Just moving the code to *init* doesn't change what it affects.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the template with JavaScript, with something like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
        {% for val in disable %}
        $('input[name="status"][value="{{ val }}"]').attr('disabled', true);
        {% endfor %}
    });
</script>
```

Assuming that you've got jQuery (for the `$`) and `disable` (in the `{% for %}` loop) is a variable you pass to the template, which evaluates to the list of values that you want grayed out.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach. It's not clear to me how I would *reference* each field - subscript? Or does Django assign a default name? (Also, I'm starting the site without JS, and will add it eventually, as I identify areas of best use).

Comment: the 'input[name="status"]' part will find all your fields, called status, just like in the form.  the '[value="{{ val }}"]' part will choose one particular radio button.  combined with the for-loop, you end up disabling all required fields.  the default name, is the name of the field - 'status'.

Comment: You would still have to check it server side, since someone could just modify the HTML.